# You need to build spark before running this program

Tags: apache-spark

I downloaded the pre-built spark 1.2.1 for hadoop 2.4. I then attempted to launch the spark shell using ./bin/spark-shell, and I got the following error message:

Failed to find Spark assembly in /Users/XXXX/Software Libraries/Java Libraries/General/spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib
You need to build Spark before running this program.

Why is it failing to launch with this error even though I downloaded the pre-built version?

Answer (score 4):

Bizarre though it may seem, moving into my home directory solves the problem. Perhaps something to do with that fact that my directory names have spaces in them, but I can't be sure.

Comment: Noticed the same issue. Had initially Spark in "C:\Program Files", moving it to "C:" solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

build/mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 -DskipTests clean package